# Images appearing haphazardly in gridView while using android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gridview, gallery

I've recently started with android development on Studio, and am trying to build an app where I use the camera to click a pic and display it in the gallery of that app. It's a basic scenario like in all photo apps these days - a camera and a gallery to show the pics clicked by THAT app itself.

I've managed to integrate camera and I'm now working on the gallery part. I used grid view to make the layout of the gallery activity, but it is not working out well, as the images are coming out a bit haphazardly.

Below is my code for the "GridViewAdapter.java" -

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare variables
    private Activity activity;
    private String[] filepath;
    private String[] filename;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
        activity = a;
        filepath = fpath;
        filename = fname;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filepath.length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);

        // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        //image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(215, 215));
        image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

        // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**I've commented out the image.setLayoutParams() line because it is causing my app to crash.**

And this is the corresponding .xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The output that I'm getting is - [screenShot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mFvq.png)

I started developing apps this week only, so I will be highly grateful for any help provided here.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Below is the code for "grid_item_layout.xml" -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please add grid_item_layout.xml source code also

Comment: Done that @RahulKumar

Answer (score 0):

```
  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="3"/>
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks @RahulKumar , that just made it perfect :)